# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: string is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a simple condition in my Express JS API endpoint, where I use typeof to check if the value entered is a string.

```
if (!name || typeof name != 'string') {
    res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      message: 'Please enter the meal name correctly! (Hint: name must be a string)'
    });
}
```

The problem is it keeps throwing this error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: string is not defined`. What's wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you are using `string` as variable name somewhere in the code which is causing the error. Can you post more code?

Comment: The error says you are referring to a `string` variable which hasn't been defined. The posted code has no reference to `string` variable! You need to provide more context.

Comment: The error you are getting does not come from the code you have shown us.

Comment: Just discovered. You all were right